# Connecting to shards in MongoDB mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, port, sharding, mongo-shell

I'm following the tutorial in the *MongoDB: The Definitive Guide*, 2nd edition, for a databases course, and it appears not to work in version 3.6.2.

Basically I have two `mongo` shells opened using `mongo --nodb`.

Then, in the first, I run `cluster = new ShardingTest({"shards": 3, "chunksize": 1})` (which works and produces a steady stream of output).

In the second shell, the book says to run `db = (new Mongo("localhost:30999")).getDB("test")` which fails. I was told by a colleague instead to run `db = (new Mongo("localhost:20000")).getDB("test")`, which worked.

Then, I inserted data which worked as well. However, when trying `sh.status()`, I got the message `printShardingStatus: this db does not have sharding enabled. be sure you are connecting to a mongos from the shell and not to a mongod.`

After searching online, I figured I'd run `sh.enableSharding(db)` which also gave me the following error:

```
2018-03-01T11:05:22.654-0500 E QUERY     [thread1] Error: not connected to a mongos :
sh._checkMongos@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:8:15
sh._adminCommand@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:18:9
sh.enableSharding@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:98:12
@(shell):1:1
```

I'm running on a Windows 10 machine, and have the correct environmental variables set up and the `db` folder created, so any help/pointers would be much appreciated!

EDIT 1:

This error persists even if `db.collection.ensureIndex()` is run first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try connecting to the shell on port 20006 by opening a new `mongo --nodb`, then do `db = (new Mongo("localhost:20006")).getDB("test")`

This should open the mongos for all the shards, so now the command `sh.status()` should work, as well as other commands like setting balancer state and starting balancer.

Comment: Yep, it was this simple, just a port issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The commands bellow show how to run 3 shards instances and 3 config instances in your localhost. For each of these shards also are created 3 replica sets (mongod instances), may it can help you:

## clean everything up

```
echo "killing mongod and mongos"
killall mongod
killall mongos
echo "removing data files"
rm -rf /data/config
rm -rf /data/shard*
```

## start a replica set and tell it that it will be shard0

```
echo "starting servers for shard 0"
mkdir -p /data/shard0/rs0 /data/shard0/rs1 /data/shard0/rs2
mongod --replSet s0 --logpath "s0-r0.log" --dbpath /data/shard0/rs0 --port 37017 --fork --shardsvr
mongod --replSet s0 --logpath "s0-r1.log" --dbpath /data/shard0/rs1 --port 37018 --fork --shardsvr
mongod --replSet s0 --logpath "s0-r2.log" --dbpath /data/shard0/rs2 --port 37019 --fork --shardsvr

sleep 5
```

## connect to one server and initiate the set

```
echo "Configuring s0 replica set"
mongo --port 37017 << 'EOF'
config = { _id: "s0", members:[
          { _id : 0, host : "localhost:37017" },
          { _id : 1, host : "localhost:37018" },
          { _id : 2, host : "localhost:37019" }]};
rs.initiate(config)
EOF
```

## start a replicate set and tell it that it will be a shard1

```
echo "starting servers for shard 1"
mkdir -p /data/shard1/rs0 /data/shard1/rs1 /data/shard1/rs2
mongod --replSet s1 --logpath "s1-r0.log" --dbpath /data/shard1/rs0 -port 47017 --fork --shardsvr
mongod --replSet s1 --logpath "s1-r1.log" --dbpath /data/shard1/rs1 --port 47018 --fork --shardsvr
mongod --replSet s1 --logpath "s1-r2.log" --dbpath /data/shard1/rs2 --port 47019 --fork --shardsvr

sleep 5

echo "Configuring s1 replica set"
mongo --port 47017 << 'EOF'
config = { _id: "s1", members:[
          { _id : 0, host : "localhost:47017" },
          { _id : 1, host : "localhost:47018" },
          { _id : 2, host : "localhost:47019" }]};
rs.initiate(config)
EOF
```

## start a replicate set and tell it that it will be a shard2

```
echo "starting servers for shard 2"
mkdir -p /data/shard2/rs0 /data/shard2/rs1 /data/shard2/rs2
mongod --replSet s2 --logpath "s2-r0.log" --dbpath /data/shard2/rs0 --port 57017 --fork --shardsvr
mongod --replSet s2 --logpath "s2-r1.log" --dbpath /data/shard2/rs1 --port 57018 --fork --shardsvr
mongod --replSet s2 --logpath "s2-r2.log" --dbpath /data/shard2/rs2 --port 57019 --fork --shardsvr

sleep 5

echo "Configuring s2 replica set"
mongo --port 57017 << 'EOF'
config = { _id: "s2", members:[
      { _id : 0, host : "localhost:57017" },
      { _id : 1, host : "localhost:57018" },
      { _id : 2, host : "localhost:57019" }]};
rs.initiate(config)
EOF
```

## now start 3 config servers

```
echo "Starting config servers"
mkdir -p /data/config/config-a /data/config/config-b /data/config/config-c
mongod --replSet csReplSet --logpath "cfg-a.log" --dbpath /data/config/config-a --port 57040 --fork --configsvr
mongod --replSet csReplSet --logpath "cfg-b.log" --dbpath /data/config/config-b --port 57041 --fork --configsvr
mongod --replSet csReplSet --logpath "cfg-c.log" --dbpath /data/config/config-c --port 57042 --fork --configsvr

echo "Configuring configuration server replica set"
mongo --port 57040 << 'EOF'
config = { _id: "csReplSet", members:[
          { _id : 0, host : "localhost:57040" },
          { _id : 1, host : "localhost:57041" },
          { _id : 2, host : "localhost:57042" }]};
rs.initiate(config)
EOF
```

## now start the mongos on a standard port

```
mongos --logpath "mongos-1.log" --configdb csReplSet/localhost:57040,localhost:57041,localhost:57042 --fork
echo "Waiting 60 seconds for the replica sets to fully come online"
sleep 60
echo "Connnecting to mongos and enabling sharding"
```

## add shards and enable sharding on the test db

```
mongo <<'EOF'
use admin
db.runCommand( { addshard : "s0/localhost:37017" } );
db.runCommand( { addshard : "s1/localhost:47017" } );
db.runCommand( { addshard : "s2/localhost:57017" } );
db.runCommand( { enableSharding: "test" } );
db.runCommand( { shardCollection: "test.some_collection", key: { some_id:1 } } );
EOF
```

Comment: So this might be crazy, but how recent are these additions? The guide I'm using is from 2013 and it doesn't mention any of this (basically, it only uses the code above). I guess I should also mention that `enableSharding` and `addshard` are not recognized as commands.

Comment: Actually, I have completed a course from mongo university about it last week :)

Comment: try this one, it is pretty straight forward

Comment: Wooh! It worked, I followed lots of tutorial but this one worked for me hey @romulomadu can you please connect with me on linked or gmail https://www.linkedin.com/in/abhimanyu0301/

Comment: Can you write something similar for multiple servers as what if the local machine will die basically how to implement this in production.